# lint-staged: what the purpose of 'git add' command

Tags: git, lint, lint-staged

Recently I started to introduce `lint-staged` into my Frontend build tool chain. And when I checked the document about it, I always find it works as following:

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    },
"lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "eslint --fix src/",
      "tslint --fix --project .",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
```

and you can find more similar usage in the link: https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged

My confusing point is the last command `git add`, what's the purpose of that?

My understand is `lint-staged` only validate the code in staged area after  `git add` and before `git commit`. So can't understand why we need to add one more `git add` again.

Comment: `--fix` probably *rewrites* the files according to some sort of rules, so now the re-written files in the work-tree need to be copied over the earlier, not-rewritten files that *you* had copied into the staging area earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's using husky to hooks some actions before your commit. See at: https://github.com/typicode/husky

`lint-staged` just changes your code and make it linting (It runs before commit by **husky**). After changed, you need add it again to update **git index**. And your changes will be effect in your commit.

Comment: 2020 update: since lint-staged@10.0.0 you can omit `git add` in the config.

Comment: When not using lint-staged@10.0.0, what happens to unstaged files during the `git add`?

Answer (score 32):

You don't need `git add` since lint-staged 10

> From v10.0.0 onwards any new modifications to originally staged files
> will be automatically added to the commit. If your task previously
> contained a `git add` step, please remove this. The automatic
> behaviour ensures there are less race-conditions, since trying to run
> multiple git operations at the same time usually results in an error.

Source: https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#v10

Comment: Here is that link for that answer https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#v10